# How to plot a very large data set (date,time (x axis) vs values recorded(y-axis) every 15 mins daily for a a year) in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am supposed to prepare an x vs y graph in python. My data set consists of Date - Time and Temperature which is recorded in an interval of 15 mins year long. Let say I have data of one month and I tried to plot it in Matplotlib. I am getting a graph which is not that clear because the x-axis (data-time) is filled throughout the axis and I am not getting a clear picture whereas Excel gives a good plot comparing to matplotlib.

The code I use to open 30 individual daily csv data recorded files and concatenating it to form one data frame is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import tkinter as tk
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time
from tkinter import filedialog
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)
files = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True) 
%gui tk
var = root.tk.splitlist(files)
filePaths = []
for f in var:
    df = pd.read_csv(f,skiprows=8, index_col=None, header=0, parse_dates=True, squeeze=True, encoding='ISO-8859–1', names=['Date', 'Time', 'Temperature', 'Humidty']) #, 
    filePaths.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(filePaths, axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index=False, sort=True, verify_integrity=False, levels=None) 
    df["Time period"] = df["Date"] + df["Time"]
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplots(figsize=(25,20))
    plt.plot('Time period', 'Temperature', data=df, linewidth=2, color='g')
    plt.title('Temperature distribution Graph')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.grid(True)
```

Example of data

[image]

The output graph looks like this:

[image]
As you can see in the output graph is flourished with the data points on the x axis and it is not in a readable form. Also, matplotlib give multiple graphs if I load and concatenate .csv files for a group of days.

The same data set plotted in Excel/Libre gives a smooth graph with oderly arranged dates on the x axis and the line graph is also perfect.

[image]

I want to rewrite my code to plot a graph similar to one plotted in Excel/Libre. Please help

Comment: @Anita Hello Anita, could you please help me with this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

Use [date locators](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/dates_api.html) to format the x-axis with the date range you require.
Date locators can be used to define intervals in seconds, minutes, ...:

- **SecondLocator:** Locate seconds
- **MinuteLocator:** Locate minutes
- **HourLocator:** Locate hours
- **DayLocator:** Locate specified days of the month
- **MonthLocator:** Locate months
- **YearLocator:** Locate years

In the example, I use the `MinuteLocator`, with 15 minutes interval.

**Import `matplotlib.dates` to work dates in plots:**

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
```

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Get your data**

```
# Sample data
# Data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['07/14/2020', '07/14/2020', '07/14/2020', '07/14/2020'],
    'Time': ['12:15:00 AM', '12:30:00 AM', '12:45:00 AM', '01:00:00 AM'],
    'Temperature': [22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 23.0]
})
```

**Convert `Time period` from String to Date object:**

```
# Convert data to Date and Time
df["Time period"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
```

**Define `min` and `max` interval:**

```
min = min(df['Time period'])
max = max(df['Time period'])
```

**Create your plot:**

```
# Plot

# Create figure and plot space
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
```

**Set time interval using locators:**

```
# Set Time Interval
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=15))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

**Set your plot options and plot:**

```
# Set labels
ax.set(xlabel="Time",
       ylabel="Temperature",
       title="Temperature distribution Graph", xlim=[min , max])

# Plot chart
ax.plot('Time period', 'Temperature', data=df, linewidth=2, color='g')
ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there any way to automate this ticks depending on the data frame[Time Period].

Comment: Yes there is. I am still editing... I will try to show...

Comment: I am getting an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: df['Time Period'] consists of dates and times. Please see the above dataframe head

Comment: It is possible. You need to create the column Time Period with data in date format. In your case you just concatenate date and time resulting in a column with strings

Comment: If I create a column with Time period with data in date format. The output gives an error

`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9e5ba2677745> in <module>
      4 plt.title('Temperature distribution Graph')
      5 plt.xlabel('Time period')
----> 6 min = min(df['Time'])
      7 max = max(df['Time'])
      8 num_int = 300 # number is intervals required, adjust for your needs

TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not callable`

Comment: I made a edit with a different approach... I am updating the explanation.

Comment: I executed the code according to your update. It shows an error as the min and max () allow only object like string, list, tuple etc. not timestamp.


TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not callable

Comment: Try to put the min and max value manually... check if it works, if it does you just need to find away to get the min and max.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: The answer's exact code give the following error: TypeError: Cannot compare type Timedelta with type float